# Cannot Import Flask_Login

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, importerror, flask-login

I am trying to import `flask-login`. When I try doing `from flask-login import *`, I get this error:

```py
C:\Users\---\Downloads\materials-master\materials-master\flask-google-login>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_login import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login.0'
```

Edit: I can do `import flask_login` and it works just fine, but when I do `from flask_login import *` it gives me the error. This error only happens when I try doing `from flask_login import *`. I f I do not `import *` it works fine.

I am using python 3.8.3 64-bit on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lays in flask_login's **init**'s first line which is as follows:

```
from .__about__ import __version__
```

importing the string **version** from the **about** file:

```
__version_info__ = ('0', '4', '1')
__version__ = '.'.join(__version_info__)
```

returning 041, thus 'flask_login.0'

when I manually removed the first line of **init** (to verify it's the problem), "from flask_login import *" did work, but you can't do this as it's not practical, especially on server side, therefore I suggest if you would like to import everything from flask_login, to just:

```
import flask_login as fl
```

then on your file do something like:

```
fl.logout_user()
```

or better, always import just what you need

Comment: Thank you for your help!